# xpath selectors not returning a match

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

This is the piece of HTML code : -

```
source1 = '

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Gemara</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Kiddushin</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Morning</font></td>

        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">12-04-2104</font></td>

        <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">
        <a href="#" onClick="listen('05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3')"><img src="images/play_audio.gif" border="0"></a>
        <a href="#" onClick="mydownload('05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3')"><img src="images/download.gif" border="0"></a>
        </td>
        <!-- <td bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">

        <a href="http://mgr.uvault.com/yadavraham/media//05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3">Download</a> 
        </td>
        -->
    </tr>
'
```

I am able to parse all pieces of data from the HTML, Only the Mp3 filename parse is not returning any values

Please see my code below:

```
from lxml import html
source2 = html.fromstring(str(source1))

Category = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@bgcolor="#ffffff"][1]//text()')
Book = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@bgcolor="#ffffff"][2]//text()')
Section = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@bgcolor="#ffffff"][3]//text()')
Date = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@bgcolor="#ffffff"][4]//text()')
Mp3filename = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@colspan=2]//a[1]//@onClick')
print Category, Book, Section, Date, Mp3filename
```

Mp3filename variable returning Null value . Is my Xapth Query right ?

Comment: You missed the `<font>` tag.

Comment: @KlausD. That isn't needed , The path is set to be Absolute //a[1] . If i replace //a[1]//@onClick' to //a[1]//@href' , it does returns '#'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `lxml.html` converts attribute names to lower-case (tested in python 2.7, HTML copy-pasted from the question with no change) :

```
raw= '''<tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Gemara</font></td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Kiddushin</font></td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Morning</font></td>

                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">12-04-2104</font></td>

                                    <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">
                                    <a href="#" onClick="listen('05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3')"><img src="images/play_audio.gif" border="0"></a>
                                    <a href="#" onClick="mydownload('05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3')"><img src="images/download.gif" border="0"></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Tahoma" Size="2">

                                    <a href="http://mgr.uvault.com/yadavraham/media//05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3">Download</a> 
                                    </td>
                                    -->
                                    </tr>'''

from lxml import html
source2 = html.fromstring(raw)

Mp3filename = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@colspan=2]//a[1]')
print html.tostring(Mp3filename[0])
# output :
# <a href="#" onclick="listen('05-115-08-2104-12-04.mp3')"><img src="images/play_audio.gif" border="0"></a>
#             ^notice that the attribute name changed to lower-case
```

So I'd suggest to try using lower-case `@onclick` in your XPath :

```
Mp3filename = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@colspan=2]//a[1]/@onclick')
```

Comment: Man that was awesome , I never knew lxml converts attribute nodesets to lowercase . This is called Experienced man detailed eye .

I made it this - Mp3filename = source2.xpath('//tr[1]//td[@colspan=2]//font[@face="Tahoma"]//a[1][@href="#"]//@onclick');Mp3filename=str(Mp3filename[0]).replace("listen('",'').replace("')",'').strip()

Answer (score 0):

first fix your HTML so it's valid xml.

you're missing  closing tag for the `<font>` in that last `<td>`. Therefor XPath won't find any valid xml below that.

Comment: I did html.fromstring(source) , therefore there is no need to convert the html to any xml schema . Thanks for your suggestion anyways .